# How to simplify the multiplication of Bessel and modified Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: special-functions

I was wondering if anyone can help me with the procedure of simplifying the following formula:
$$
e^{ - \beta x} \mathcal{T}_b \sum\limits_m {i^m J_m (kr)e^{im(\theta  - \alpha )} } 
$$
using the following identity:
$$
e^{ - \beta x}  = e^{ - \beta b} \sum\limits_s {( - 1)^s I_s (\beta r)e^{is\theta } } 
$$
to the following formula in which the index of the modified Bessel function is modified to $m-s$:
$$
e^{ - \beta b} \sum\limits_m {( - 1)^m U_m (r)e^{im\theta } } 
$$
where $U_m$ is equal to
$$
\mathcal{T}_b \sum\limits_s {( - i)^s I_{m - s} (\beta r)J_s (kr)e^{ - is\alpha } } .
$$
In these formulas $\theta$, $\alpha$, and $x$ are arbitrary real variables and $m$ and $s$ are integers varying from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and other variables are constant.
Also $x = b + r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Next time please use MathJax to format your equations. The answer to your question: multiply the first and the second equations and collect the coefficient of the different powers of $e^{i\theta}$. If you call $z=e^{i\theta}$, it is just a multiplication of Laurent series.

Comment: How I_(m-s) term is created? @Gary

Comment: Think about power series first. Do you know the Cauchy product of two power series? It is $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {a_m x^m } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {b_m x^m } } \right) = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{s = 0}^m {a_{m - s} b_s } } \right)x^m } .
$$ Can you see that $m-s$?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary